# Get all the instances of recurring event with CAML Query / jQuery SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, jquery

I need all the recurring event instances, i.e If the recurring date range is **04th October 2016 to 6th October 2016** then I need all the events like **04th October 2016, 05th October 2016, 06th October 2016**.
All the instance of the recurring event with CAML Query, jQuery/JSOM/Client Object Model.
Is it possible and how?

Comment: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/26/use-spservices-to-get-recurring-events-as-distinct-items-aspx/
Is it possible to work with the Web Root Calendar list instead of App Model list?
It is not accessible for me to the Web Root Calendar list.
Did anybody let me know further, How can I get the all instances of recurrence event?

Comment: Still looking for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting

```
<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
```

in the `<QueryOptions>` of your CAML?